# Inequality between random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X_k$ be $\text{i.i.d.}$ continuous random variables. Find in
>   terms of $n:$ $$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_1\geq X_2\geq\cdots \geq
>  X_{n-1}<X_n\Big)$$

Let each $X_k$ have $\text{p.d.f }\;f$ and $\text{c.d.f}\;F$, so that:
$$f_{X_1,\;\dots,\; X_n}(x_1,\;\dots,\; x_n)=f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)$$
The probability should $(?)$ resemble something like:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_{n-2}}\color{red}{\int_{?}^?}f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)\;\color{red}{\mathrm{d}x_n}\mathrm{d}x_{n-1}\cdots\mathrm{d}x_1$$
The problem is that I cannot see how to incorporate $\color{red}{X_{n-1}<X_n}$ into the limits. Ignoring this the expression becomes:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(f(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\left(f(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_{n-2}}f(x_{n-1})\mathrm{d}x_{n-1}\right)\cdots\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n!}}$$
By using $\int_{-\infty}^{x_{k}}f(x_{k+1})\mathrm{d}x_{k+1}=F(x_{k})$ repeatedly.
I believe this is the $\color{blue}{\text{correct}}$ result, but I have arrived at it via a flawed reasoning. How can I adjust my working?

**Note:** I am not interested in an different approach at the minute, however slick; I'd like to see how this is done using the method above so that I gain a greater understanding of the subject.

Comment: What does the stated event mean? $\{X_1 \geq X_2 \geq \ldots \geq X_{n-1}\} \cap \{X_n > X_{n-1}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Set the limits so that the innermost integral is over the interval $[x_{n-1},\infty)$. Then this integral is

$$\int_{x_{n-1}}^{\infty}f(x_n)dx_n = 1-F(x_{n-1})$$

The iterated integral over the remaining variables splits into two pieces resulting in

$$P= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}(1-\frac{1}{n})$$

Answer (score 0):

To continue your argument, use $\int_{x_{n-1}}^{+\infty} \cdots dx_n =  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cdots dx_n - \int_{-\infty}^{x_{n-1}} \cdots dx_n$

Put it in another way, what you look for is $P(X_1 \geq \cdots \geq X_{n-1}) - P(X_1 \geq \cdots \geq X_{n-1}\geq X_n)$